# Custom gem dependencies not added to Gemfile.lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I wrote a gem. In my Gem's gemspec file, I have something like this:

```
 spec.add_development_dependency "aws-sdk-mturk", '~> 1.3'
```

And in one of my Gem's files I have:

```
require 'aws-sdk-mturk'
```

This gem is not published to rubygems.org. It is a private gem on my private git account. So I wanted to add it to my Rails project and so I did this in Gemfile:

```
gem "my_gem", git: "https://git.mygitlab.net/myuser/mygem.git", branch: "master"
```

And I notice when I run `bundle install` and then subsequently `bundle update --source mygem`, in Gemfile.lock it does not show any of the dependencies, including aws-sdk-mturk.

So when I try to run Rails application, I get this error:

```
gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- aws-sdk-mturk (LoadError)
```

When doesn't bundler/the Rails application read the .gemspec dependencies of my private gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `add_development_dependency` to `add_runtime_dependency` if your code needs this other gem during runtime.

Quote from https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#declaring-dependencies

> **Runtime vs. development**
>
> RubyGems provides two main “types” of dependencies: runtime and development. Runtime dependencies are what your gem needs to work
>   (such as rails needing activesupport).
>
> Development dependencies are useful for when someone wants to make modifications to your gem. When you specify development dependencies,
>   another developer can run gem install --dev your_gem and RubyGems will
>   grab both sets of dependencies (runtime and development). Typical
>   development dependencies include test frameworks and build systems.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `add_runtime_dependency` instead `add_development_dependency`.

From the [docs](https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_development_dependency)

> Development dependencies aren't installed by default and aren't
>   activated when a gem is required.